# Get response from Poco http client to string

Tags: c++, http, stream, httpclient, poco

I have a small code that sends a POST HTTP call to a local web service and gets a response, using the Poco library. Currently I have the response message printed in the terminal with cout.

```
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPClientSession.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPRequest.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPResponse.h"
#include "Poco/StreamCopier.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace Poco::Net;
using namespace Poco;

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    HTTPClientSession s("localhost", 8000);
    HTTPRequest request(HTTPRequest::HTTP_POST, "/test");
    s.sendRequest(request);

    HTTPResponse response;
    std::istream& rs = s.receiveResponse(response);
    StreamCopier::copyStream(rs, cout);

    return 0;
}
```

How can I have the response message stored in a char array or string and not printed or stored in a file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Poco, but you could just replace `std::cout` with [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) and then pull the string out of it.

So instead of doing:

```
StreamCopier::copyStream(rs, cout);
```

use this code

```
#include <sstream>
// ...
std::ostringstream oss;
StreamCopier::copyStream(rs, oss);
std::string response = oss.str();
// use "response" ...
```

Or, more directly, you can use [`copyToString`](http://www.appinf.com/docs/poco/Poco.StreamCopier.html#21220) to copy directly into a `std::string`, saving yourself at least one allocation+copy:

```
std::string responseStr;
StreamCopier::copyToString(rs, responseStr);
// use "responseStr" ...
```

Comment: Better yet, replace it with [`copyToString`](http://www.appinf.com/docs/poco/Poco.StreamCopier.html#21220).

Comment: If only I had noticed this function... Both ways work fine. Thank you both!